# How to change the path of Meteor DDP (websocket) requests?

Tags: meteor, websocket, ddp

Is it possible to change the path of Meteor's own websocket (DDP) requests? I need it to setup load balancers properly.

For example: changing this path "ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/839/ui4qa1rb/websocket" to “ws://localhost:3000/something/sockjs/839/ui4qa1rb/websocket"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by setting ROOT_URL property.